# How do I tell the diffrence between an empty list of MX records and a DNS error in Go?

Tags: go, dns

I'm trying to deliver mail. Whenever I want to send an email to "example@gmail.com" I do a DNS lookup to get a list of MX records for "gmail.com"

```golang
mxs, err := net.LookupMX(domain)
```

For domains with MX records this is simple enough, however [RFC 5321 section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5.1) says

> If an empty list of MXs is returned, the address is treated as if it
> was associated with an implicit MX RR, with a preference of 0,
> pointing to that host.

so if a domain has no MX records (like chat.google.com) I need to send mail to "chat.google.com" directly. In order to do this I need to detect when `net.LookupMX()` gets an empty response. The issue is that `net.LookupMX()` considers an empty response an error. I put together a little test to demonstrate this:

```golang
var resolver net.Resolver
for _, preferGo := range []bool{true, false} {
    for _, strictErrors := range []bool{true, false} {
        resolver.PreferGo = preferGo
        resolver.StrictErrors = strictErrors
        fmt.Printf("PreferGo: %v\tStrictErrors: %v\t", preferGo, strictErrors)
        result, err := resolver.LookupMX(context.Background(), "chat.google.com")
        fmt.Printf("Result: %v\tError: %v\n", result, err)
    }
}
```

```
PreferGo: true  StrictErrors: true      Result: []      Error: lookup chat.google.com on 10.64.15.252:53: no such host
PreferGo: true  StrictErrors: false     Result: []      Error: lookup chat.google.com on 10.64.15.252:53: no such host
PreferGo: false StrictErrors: true      Result: []      Error: lookup chat.google.com: dnsquery: No records found for given DNS query.
PreferGo: false StrictErrors: false     Result: []      Error: lookup chat.google.com: dnsquery: No records found for given DNS query.
```

I was hoping `net.LookupMX()` would return `[], nil` for an empty result. As it is, I need to examine the error value to see if it is a "real" error (like a DNS timeout) or just an empty result. The error value appears to be platform-dependent though. I could test the `err.String()` value I get on each platform (Windows, Mac, Linux, FreeBSD, etc) and do some sort of regex comparison. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

The error from `net.LookupMX()` is usually (always?) a `net.DNSError`. If you cast it to that, you can access the `IsTimeout`, `IsTemporary`, and `IsNotFound` properties of the error, which give you easy to test information about the error.

```golang
var resolver net.Resolver
for _, preferGo := range []bool{true, false} {
    for _, strictErrors := range []bool{true, false} {
        resolver.PreferGo = preferGo
        resolver.StrictErrors = strictErrors
        fmt.Printf("PreferGo: %v\tStrictErrors: %v\t", preferGo, strictErrors)

        result, err := resolver.LookupMX(context.Background(), "chat.google.com")
        fmt.Printf("Result: %v\tError: %v\n", result, err)

        dnsErr, isDNSErr := err.(*net.DNSError)
        fmt.Printf("IsDNSError: %v", isDNSErr)
        if isDNSErr {
            fmt.Printf(
                "\tIsTimeout: %v\tIsTemporary: %v\tIsNotFound: %v",
                dnsErr.IsTimeout,
                dnsErr.IsTemporary,
                dnsErr.IsNotFound,
            )
        }

        fmt.Println()
        fmt.Println()
    }
}
```

```
PreferGo: true  StrictErrors: true  Result: []  Error: lookup chat.google.com on 10.64.15.252:53: no such host
IsDNSError: true    IsTimeout: false    IsTemporary: false  IsNotFound: true

PreferGo: true  StrictErrors: false Result: []  Error: lookup chat.google.com on 10.64.15.252:53: no such host
IsDNSError: true    IsTimeout: false    IsTemporary: false  IsNotFound: true

PreferGo: false StrictErrors: true  Result: []  Error: lookup chat.google.com: dnsquery: No records found for given DNS query.
IsDNSError: true    IsTimeout: false    IsTemporary: false  IsNotFound: false

PreferGo: false StrictErrors: false Result: []  Error: lookup chat.google.com: dnsquery: No records found for given DNS query.
IsDNSError: true    IsTimeout: false    IsTemporary: false  IsNotFound: false
```

Personally I intend to use the built-in Go resolver (`resolver.PreferGo = true`) for consistency across platforms and test that

- `err.(*net.DNSError).IsTimeout == false`
- `err.(*net.DNSError).IsTemporary == false`
- `err.(*net.DNSError).IsNotFound == true`

Hopefully this will narrow down the list of possible errors and do a decent job of identifying the ones that represent an empty result.